# Spring Boot - CrudRepository Filter

Tags: spring, api, spring-boot, filter, repository

I'm new to Spring Boot and I have started with a simple application and used CrudRepositories to offer a standard api (GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE).

- api/categories

  - The application has categories and categories have entries
  - A category can be marked as confidential
- api/entries

  - Entries in a confidential category should only be visible to users with a specific role.

Is there a simple way to achieve this with the standard exposed api of a crud repository? Or is the only secure way to implement my own api endpoints?

Category:

```
/**
 * A category.
 */
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Category extends BaseEntity {

    private String description;

    private Boolean confidential;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Entry> entries;

}
```

CategoryRepository:

```
/**
 * Spring Data CRUD repository for the Category entity.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public interface CategoryRepository extends CrudRepository<Category, Long> { }
```

Entry:

```
/**
 * A entry.
 */
@Entity
@Data
public class Entry extends AuditingEntity {

    private String title;

    private String value;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    private Category category;

}
```

EntryRepository:

```
/**
 * Spring Data CRUD repository for the Entry entity.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public interface EntryRepository extends CrudRepository<Entry, Long> {

    List<Entry> findByCategoryId(@Param("categoryId") long categoryId);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `spring-boot-starter-security` dependency to your project with little configuration should solve your issue. Basically you would like to utilize `@PreAuthorize` and/or `@PreFilter` annotations depending on your exact needs.

#### Example

Consider adjusting your `CategoryRepository`:

```
public interface CategoryRepository extends CrudRepository<Category, Long> {
    @Override
    @PreFilter("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') and filterObject.confidential")
    List<Category> findAll();
}
```

`@PreFilter` defines the rule which will be applied to every single element in the list before returning list of objects by checking user's role (`ROLE_ADMIN`) and `confidential` property of filtered object. Just adjust it to your needs.

#### Resources

- More info on using `@PreAuthorize` and `@PreFilter`: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-prefilter-postfilter.
- Go ahead and also check out following example of securing publicly exposed API utilizing Spring Boot and Spring Security: https://spring.io/blog/2015/10/28/react-js-and-spring-data-rest-part-5-security

Comment: This looks very promising. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i would do that way.

```
List<Category> categories;
if(user is not specific role)
  categories = categoryRepository.findByConfidential(false);
else
  categories = categoryRepository.findAll();
```

Later can use that list categories where is listed categories and every gategory have method getEntries() to get list of entries.